# Seeking Academic-Level Source on Justifications of Democracy: A Comprehensive Listing with Critical Perspectives

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, democracy

I have recently embarked on a quest to delve deeper into the justifications of democracy, but I must admit, the plethora of information available has left me feeling overwhelmed. There seem to be countless arguments supporting democracy, each with its own nuances and complexities. To navigate this vast landscape, I was wondering if any of you could recommend an academic-level source that provides a comprehensive listing of the strongest justifications for democracy. It would be even better if the source includes brief descriptions and critical perspectives to help me gain a well-rounded understanding of the subject matter.

While I am aware that democracy has been extensively discussed and analyzed throughout history, I believe that a curated collection of the most compelling justifications, accompanied by critical takes, would greatly assist me in my exploration. By examining a range of perspectives, I aim to foster a more nuanced understanding of the strengths and weaknesses of democratic systems.

If any of you are familiar with such a resource or have come across any articles, books, or publications that align with my quest, I would be immensely grateful for your recommendations. I trust that this community harbors a wealth of knowledge and diverse perspectives, making it an ideal place to seek guidance.

Comment: Not an academic source, but just wondering if you've been pointed towards the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy? https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/democracy/

Answer (score 1):

A most influential book on the topic is Karl Popper's Open Society and its Enemies. Written during WW2, it argues that one of the main advantages of democratic regimes over totalitarian ones is that the former can dispose of a bad leader, while the latter cannot.

Answer (score 0):

While political philosophy is largely unappealing to me, I do own and have read through [*Spheres of Justice: A Defense of Pluralism and Equality*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ndITi80AcsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=in%20defense%20of%20pluralism&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2h5q67v3_AhXTpIkEHRg2CcgQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=in%20defense%20of%20pluralism&f=false). It's not specifically a defense of democracy, per se, but it is a defense of equality, and briefly mentions Athenian politics. Direct and indirect democracy are predicated on notions that stem from the belief that people should have equal say in affairs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read Kant’s “Metaphysics of Morals” (not to be confused with his “Groundwork of the Metaphysics of Morals”).

Answer (score 0):

Well, just looking at my bookcase-of-old, it seems like the standard grad schools texts are:

- [Models of Democracy, by David Held](https://www.sup.org/books/title/?id=10597), and...
- [On Democracy, by Robert Dahl](https://yalebooks.yale.edu/book/9780300254051/on-democracy/)

The first is more tome-like, but the second is actually a pretty good read.

I'd also suggest a couple of extras, for more current-era focus:

- [Democracy and Difference, by Seyla Benhabib](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691044781/democracy-and-difference),
- [Democracy in Capitalist Times, by John Dryzek](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/democracy-in-capitalist-times-9780195106008?cc=us&lang=en&), and...
- [Power, edited by Steven Lukes](https://nyupress.org/9780814750315/power/)

The first two cover specific issues in current democratic processes, while the last is a collection of philosophical essays on political power, which is a tricky and misunderstood concept within democratic systems.

To be honest, though, the foundations of democracy are fairly straightforward, and a reading of the relevant sections of Aristotle's "Politics" is sufficient. Every society has to make collective decisions, and every member of society wants to make sure that those collective decisions benefit (or at least don't harm) themselves. When power to make collective decisions is distributed equally across society we have a pure democracy. All the rest of the discussions revolve around how best to approximate democracy in contexts where *pure* democracy is pragmatically impossible.

Note: Aristotle distinguishes between a polity (where citizens are civic-minded and competent) and a (degraded) democracy (where citizens are ignorant, intemperate, and easily manipulated). In modern political usage the term 'democracy' means what Aristotle called a 'polity', and what Aristotle called 'democracy' is usually referred to as demagoguery. The shift in terminology can be confusing, but don't let it throw you.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but I doubt anyone can offer you a shortcut. To begin with, the definitions and possible structures of "rule by the demos" are endlessly disputable.

You might try "Can Democracy Work?" by New School philosophy prof James Miller, for an intelligent yet mainstream and accessible historical overview.

Since "democracy" has become an ill-defined political buzzword, you might be better off reading criticisms of the whole idea of "democracy," from Plato to James Madison to Lenin.

The idea that all human beings share something in common, some "equality," is as old at least as Stoicism and Christianity. How this is best actualized in real political structures is a vexed problem, to say the least.

For many people, myself included, the idea of "democracy" is an ongoing historical process that has almost nothing to do with the vile claims of contemporary nations, like the U.S.

It is a rather serious problem, a widespread mental blockage, that we can commonly associate the term "democracy" with a state structure like the U.S. Well, as I say, sorry, don't see a shortcut I can offer.

Comment: +1, particularly for 3rd and 5th paras. You could add Thoreau to the critics-set, whose criticisms have had more agency than Plato's but are less politically incorrect! I've taken the liberty to correct a typo.